# I don't understand the meaning of 'gone talk'

Tags: non-standard-english

[image]

I saw the picture like above on the internet.
But I don't understand the meaning of gone talk grammatically.
Is there any abbreviation or omission in the sentence?
Please, give me the instruction here.

Comment: It's "badly-written". Should be *He **knows** his girl [is] **going to** talk about it all day.* Don't use things like this to learn English.

Comment: It's similar to saying 말할 거요 instead of 말할 거예요.

Answer (score 3):

That sentence is written in African-American Vernacular English. In it, the word "gone" is used as an alternative spelling of the word "gonna".

If that sentence were written in standard English, I think it would say, "He knows his girl is going to talk about it all day."

As an English student, learning how to recognize and understand AAVE is probably a good idea. Keep in mind that if you *use* AAVE yourself, other people may think that you're speaking incorrectly, or that you're purposely imitating African-Americans, or both. People might perceive your speech as being racist.